# Вводная конструкция или нет?

Tags: вводные-слова

По объективным данным испытуемый демонстрирует нормативный уровень развития интеллекта. Нужна ли запятая после слова "данным"?

Answer (score 4):

Возможны оба варианта:

1) **Вводное слово (источник информации)**

***По объективным данным***, испытуемый демонстрирует нормативный уровень развития интеллекта.

2) **Необособленное наречное выражение**

***По объективным данным*** испытуемый демонстрирует нормативный уровень развития интеллекта.

**В чем смысловое различие?**

В первом случае вывод уже сделан, а основание для того вывода указывается как дополнительная информация.

Во втором случае вывод делается в соответствии с объективными данными, наречное выражение входит в состав предложения.

Answer (score 1):

Запятая может быть употреблена в случае, как Вы правильно сказали, наличия вводного сочетания, в данном случае обозначающего источник информации. Но ставить запятую или нет — решать только Вам. Оба варианта являются нормативными, однако смысл будет немного отличаться.